# TypeError: MongoStore is not a Constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

I am making a website with google authentication. I try to store my session in my mongodb database. But when I add the store option to my express session, it keeps giving the following error.

```
TypeError: MongoStore is not a constructor
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Website\animetography\mongodb\app.js:42:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

My app.js code is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');(session);
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

//Load Config

dotenv.config({path: './config/config.env'});

//Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);


connectDB();

const app = express();

//Logging
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use('morgan'('dev'));
}

//Handebars

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// Express Sessions

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  })
);

// Passport Middleware

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Static folder

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//ROUTES
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000


app.listen(port,
    console.log(`Server Running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${port}`)
    );
```

The error occurs at:

```
store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure out why this error is occurring.

Comment: In docs they have this `const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo').default;` <=== **.default**  Your code `const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');(session);` Why the `(session);` ??

Comment: The session stores the express-session I'm using. When I am logged in and refresh the page, what happens is that it logs me out. I want the session to be saved in my mongo database so that when I refresh the page, the page doesn't kick me out. That's why I'm using session

Comment: So I found a solution: The method I used is old and doesn't work with the latest versions of connect-mongo. Instead of `(session)`, I used `.default` in my require and in the express session I used the following: `app.use(session({ store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI }).` This worked perfectly.

Comment: Related: [MongoStore.create({ ..............Cannot read property 'create' of undefined](/q/69150088/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method used to connect to MongoDB using connect-mongo is old and doesn't work with the latest versions of connect-mongo. Instead of `(session)` use the `.default` in

`const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');(session);`

so that it looks like

`const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo').default;`

and in the express session use the following:

`app.use(session({ store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI, options...})`

This solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest documentation: https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/commit/f18dae083aec690f4f9a8f81283c99cf994b0558

```
`const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo').default;`
```

should not be used anymore, but

> `const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');`

should be used instead.

The rest is correct, the documentation recommends using

```
app.use(session({secret: 'foo',
  store: MongoStore.create(options)
}));
```

options must include the client, the mongoUrl or the clientpromise

```
app.use(session({
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost/test-app' })
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

check this line

```
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
```

Removing the new should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `connect-mongo` use [`connect-mongodb-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongodb-session) and it should work

```
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
```